# Android AlarmManager waking application with different intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

Our application uses AlarmManager to wake the application with a certain PendingIntent, this intent is always passed correctly to our onReceive-method. In the following code alarmid and alarmuser has the correct information:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("alarmid", intent.getIntExtra("id", -1));
    i.putExtra("alarmuser", intent.getStringExtra("user"));
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

But when calling startActivity with this intent, the extra data is only supplied if the onCreate-method is called. So this code works fine and the variables are set:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(getIntent().hasExtra("alarmid") && getIntent().hasExtra("alarmuser")) {
        String alarmId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("alarmid");
        String alarmUser = getIntent().getExtras().getString("alarmuser");
    }
}
```

However, if onRestart is used, we get an empty intent (no extras). I.e. this code does not work, and the variables will be never be set:

```
@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    if(getIntent().hasExtra("alarmid") && getIntent().hasExtra("alarmuser")) {
        String alarmId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("alarmid");
        String alarmUser = getIntent().getExtras().getString("alarmuser");
    }
}
```

Hence, onStart (which obviously is called after both onCreate and onRestart) sometimes has our extras in the intent and sometimes not.

Are we doing something wrong or is this expected?

Comment: `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` this line can be your problem. Try to remove it and try again. If it doesn't help try to pass your variables to static variables so you wont lose them.